# Is there an existing service/extension to notify changes of any file in a particular folder in google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to get notified when any files in my specific google drive folder changes.  Surprisingly, I only see that I can manually configure the notification for each file.  I didn't see a way to configure the notification for any file in a folder.  Since I have many files in the folder, I'd like to find an easier way to do it in stead of manually configuring each file.

Obviously one of the ways is to write a program to do it.  But before doing it, does anyone know if there is an existing service to do it?  The task of monitoring a google drive folder seems to be a normal one and I suspect there could be readily available services or libraries to do so?